# Responsive filemanager | The upload folder there isn't. Check your config.php file

Tags: php, jquery, html, plugins

I use stand alone responsive file manager when dialog box is open then no folder is appear there and Error is: The upload folder there isn't. Check your `config.php` file.

I pass the all url value in config.php file of responsive_filemanager->filemanger->config->config.php(i have use `myconfig.php` file variables values here using json file ).
Please help me out.

DEMO_LINK = [Using as Stand-alone file manager](http://www.responsivefilemanager.com/demo.php)
DOCUMENTATION_LINK = [DOCUMENTATION](http://www.responsivefilemanager.com/)

my directory structure is following

```
-www(root)
  -myweb
     -responsive_filemanager
  -wallpaper
     -sub_folder1
         img1
         img2 & more
     -sub_folder1
         img1
         img2 & more
```

my config.php

```
<?php
    $base_url =$_POST['base_url'];
    if($base_url != ""){
        $url=$base_url;
    }else{
        //$url=((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http"). "://". @$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/football/responsive_filemanager";
        $url =((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http"). "://". @$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    }
    $myconfig=array(

        'main_url'=>$url,

        'upload_dir' => '/wallpaper/',

        'current_path' => '../wallpaper/',

        'thumbs_base_path' => '../thumbs/',

        'multiple_selection' => false,

        'multiple_selection_action_button' => false
    );
    $array_data[]=$myconfig;
    file_put_contents("config.json",json_encode($array_data));
    chmod("config.json",0777);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change here

**'current_path' => '../../../wallpaper/'**

Comment: Welcome Bro @Sunnymori